# Making bitmasks in C

Tags: c, bitmask

I'm new to bit manipulation but I'm struggling to translate it to code.
For the following function I need to make a bitmask

```
void make_bitmask(unsigned int width, unsigned int shift,unsigned int* mask)
```

The bitmask function  is supposed to have a width and a shift. if w=5 and s=1 it should give 00111110.

How should I approach this? This is my latest code I've been trying:

```
*mask |= width << shift;

Changed to *mask = ((1 << width) - 1) << shift;
```

Unit test:

```
static void test_make_bitmask_correct_width(void)
{
 unsigned int mask = 0;
make_bitmask(1,0,&mask)
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_HEX32(0x1, mask);
make_bitmask(2,0,&mask)
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_HEX32(0x3, mask);
make_bitmask(5,0,&mask)
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_HEX32(0x1f, mask);
make_bitmask(32,0,&mask)
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_HEX32(0xffffffff, mask); // the one that is currently failing  mask is 0x000000000
```

Comment: Is the routine required to support a mask width of zero? Does it need to support a mask width equal to the `unsigned int` width (e.g., 32 bits)?

Comment: Something like this will work easy: `unsigned int mask = -1; mask <<= (32 - width); mask >>= (32 - width - shift); return mask`, not tested, you probably need to adjust a bit the values + do some error checking.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The unit tests that are written for the correct width and shift are between 1 and 32 bits.

Comment: @LucGestel: To support a width of 32 bits, with an `unsigned int` width of 32 bits, you should not use `1 << width` or `1u << width` in the code. Shifting by the width of the left operand is not defined by the C standard. It might pass some unit tests but fail when the code is changed, when compiler options are changed, or the compiler is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void make_bitmask(unsigned int width, unsigned int shift,unsigned int *mask)
{
    /*  With unlimited arithmetic, (1 << width) - 1 would give us a mask of
        width bits, starting at the low bit position.  E.g., with width 3, 1 <<
        3 would give binary 1000, and subtracting one would give 111, a mask of
        3 bits.  However, in C arithmetic, if width is the full width of an
        unsigned int, then "1u << width" would overflow.  To avoid this, if
        width is positive, we shift 2u by width-1.  If width is zero, we simply
        use the hardcoded result for a mask of zero bits, zero.
    */
    unsigned int t = width ? (2u << width-1) - 1u : 0u;

    //  Shift the mask to the desired position and store it.
    *mask = t << shift;
}
```

Comment: When trying your code I got an error: suggest parentheses around '-' inside '<<' |

Comment: @LucGestel: So put parentheses around `-` inside `<<`. The compiler is just suggesting that to avoid precedence mistakes. As my work involves using this precedence frequently, it is as familiar to me as multiplication versus addition, so I find the parentheses to be more clutter than helpful.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I usually try to suppress those warning even if the resulting code end up more cluttier sinceI had to deal with a bug because of that. Turn out that if you use -O2 flag while compiling with gcc, gcc can end up breaking the code.

Answer (score 1):

The decimal value `5` is binary `00000101`. Shifting it left by one bit gives you `00001010`.

If you want `5` to turn into `00011111` (decimal 31) then the easiest solution is to find out the value `00100000` (decimal 32) and the subtracting one.

Remembering that we're dealing with powers of 2, if you raise 2 to the power of 5 we get 32, and can then subtract one to get the base mask. But instead of using the `pow` function or multiplying in a loop, we can just shift the value `1` five steps left (`1 << 5`).

Putting it all together, the you should shift `1` left by `width` bits, subtract `1`, and then shift the result `shift` bits to the left:

```
*mask = ((1 << width) - 1) << shift;
```

With `width == 5` and `shift == 1` then the above will give you binary `00111110` (decimal 62).

Comment: This overflows when `width` is the width of `int` or one less. Bit shifting is notorious for signedness and width issues, so code like this should never be written casually, and unsigned constants such as `1u` rather than `1` are generally preferred, particularly when the target type is `unsigned int`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, with your current code I'm succeeding two out of the three unit tests that were written for this code. however one still fails.  test_bitmask_correct_width:fail: Expected 0xFFFFFFFF was 0x00000000